# How to increase heap size in Eclipse ADT v22.3

Tags: android, eclipse, heap-memory

I now there are allot questions in SO regarding this but most of them are command line arguments which I don't quite understand (I am a ammature programming from home) and  others deal with options i don't see on my version of ADT.

I have a xml that is using allot heap space and giving me out of heap space errors but I can't fix as I cannot access it.

Oddly enough I have removed all the lint errors but am still getting the heap space errors when accessing the file.

I am using ADT v22.3.0-887826.

Thanks
Ciaran

Comment: i think there is an option when we create or edit AVD, memory option just specify your heap requirement there.

Comment: I c that now, does that apply to just  that specific emulator though?

Comment: "am still getting the heap space errors when accessing the file" -- are these errors from Eclipse while programming, or from Android while running your app?

Comment: @commonsware yes they are in eclipse whilst programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Linux ADT bundle**

you need to increase size for eclipse

1) Open eclipse.ini file

looks like

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

2) Change this param

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

to

-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M

and restart eclipse

Comment: Could not find a eclipse.ini file im the eclipse directory but did find a configuration.ini file but there is no xms values in it

Comment: I think you are on windows machine. This is for linux.

Answer (score 2):

By default android allow 16 MB space for application but if application require more than this then by setting android:largeHeap="true" inside application tag in manifest you can extends your app memory allocation upto 24 MB.

Comment: Got it, I am using a Mac so eclipse.ini file I found by right clicking eclipse executable in Finder and selecting Show Package Contents